How to get file's sensitivity label from sharepoint online document library using csom
I have a requirement to get word or excel file sensitivity label  from a sharepoint online document library using CSOM.
How to achieve this. Can anyone help me on this.

Have a look at this snippet:
            string siteUrl = "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite";
            string fileUrl = "/sites/yoursite/Shared Documents/yourfile.docx";

            ClientContext context = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

            // Authenticate with your credentials (or use another method to authenticate)
            context.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials("yourusername@yourdomain.com", GetSecureString("yourpassword"));

            // Get the file from the document library
            File file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(fileUrl);
                ListItem listItem = file.ListItemAllFields;

                // Load the list item
                context.Load(listItem);
                context.ExecuteQuery();

                // Retrieve the ComplianceTag (Sensitivity Label) and Retention Label
                string sensitivityLabel = listItem["ComplianceTag"] != null ? listItem["ComplianceTag"].ToString() : "No Sensitivity Label applied.";
                string retentionLabel = listItem["RetentionLabel"] != null ? listItem["RetentionLabel"].ToString() : "No Retention Label applied.";

Here is a Powershell version. I have seen in some places a ComplianceAssetId, so you may need to check all listItem properties to make sure you are using the right one:
$siteUrl = "https://yourdomain.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $siteUrl -UseWebLogin

# Path to the file in the document library
$fileServerRelativeUrl = "/sites/yoursite/Shared Documents/yourfile.docx"

# Get the file
$file = Get-PnPFile -Url $fileServerRelativeUrl -AsListItem

# Get the sensitivity label (ComplianceAssetId)
$sensitivityLabel = $file["ComplianceAssetId"]


You could try below codes.
Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
Connect-SPOService -Url https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com
 
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\CSOM\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
      
#Config Parameters
$tenant=https://tenant.sharepoint.com
$SiteURL= https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/emilytest
$LibraryName = "TESTLIB"
  
#Get Credentials to connect
$Cred = Get-Credential
  
Try {
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.UserName,$Cred.Password)
      
    #Get the Web and List
    $Web = $Ctx.Web
    $Ctx.Load($Web)
    $List = $Web.Lists.GetByTitle($LibraryName)
    $Ctx.Load($List)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
    #Prepare the query
    $Query = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery
    $Query.ViewXml = "@
    &lt;View Scope='RecursiveAll'&gt;
        &lt;Query&gt;
            &lt;OrderBy&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='TRUE'/&gt;&lt;/OrderBy&gt;
        &lt;/Query&gt;
        &lt;RowLimit Paged='TRUE'&gt;2000&lt;/RowLimit&gt;
    &lt;/View&gt;"
  
    $Counter=1
    $DataCollection = @()
    #Batch Process items
    Do {
        #powershell sharepoint online list all documents
        $ListItems = $List.GetItems($Query) 
        $Ctx.Load($ListItems)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
        $Query.ListItemCollectionPosition = $ListItems.ListItemCollectionPosition
 
        #Iterate through each document in the library
        ForEach($ListItem in $ListItems| Where {$_.FileSystemObjectType -eq "File"})
        {
            #Display a Progress bar
            Write-Progress -Activity "Scanning Files in the Library" -Status "Collection file's Inventory '$($Item.FieldValues.FileRef)' ($Counter of $($List.ItemCount))" -PercentComplete (($Counter / $List.ItemCount) * 100)
 
            #Collect data        
            $DataCollection += New-Object PSObject -Property ([Ordered] @{
                FileName    = $ListItem.FieldValues["FileLeafRef"]
                RelativeURL = $ListItem.FieldValues["FileRef"]
                CreatedBy   = $ListItem.FieldValues["Created_x0020_By"]
                CreatedOn   = $ListItem.FieldValues["Created"]
                ModifiedBy  = $ListItem.FieldValues["Modified_x0020_By"]
                ModifiedOn  = $ListItem.FieldValues["Modified"]
                FileSize    = $ListItem.FieldValues["File_x0020_Size"]
            })
            $Counter++
        }
    }While($Query.ListItemCollectionPosition -ne $Null)
 
    #Display results
    $DataCollection 
   
}
Catch {
    write-host -f Red "Error:" $_.Exception.Message
}
      
foreach ($file in $DataCollection.Filename)
{  
Write-Host $file
$fileurl=$SiteURL+"/"+$LibraryName+"/"+$file
get-FileSensitivityLabelInfo -FileUrl $fileurl
}

